# Where is the "Invoke" member in System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon?

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to create a cmdlet with the name Invoke-Something.
But I cannot find the member "Invoke" to put in the attribute:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Invoke, "Something", SupportsShouldProcess = true)]
                    ^^^^^^
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it: VerbsLifecycle.Invoke

check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(VS.85).aspx